# LINQ to XML - check for null?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've been using LINQ for about 2 days, so please bear with me.

Here's my current code;

```
_resultList = (
from
    item in _documentRoot.Descendants("MyItems")
select
    new MyClass
    {
        XMLID = item.Attribute("id").Value
    }).ToList<MyClass>();
```

Most of the elements have an 'id' attribute, and they get added to the list successfully.
Some, however, don't have an 'id'. 
For these, I'd like 'id' to just be an empty string.

How do I check to see if the attribute exists before trying to access it?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store it in a variable and based on whether this variable is null define the value of the XMLID property:

```
from item in _documentRoot.Descendants("MyItems")
let idAttr = item.Attribute("id")
select new MyClass
{
    XMLID = idAttr != null ? idAttr.Value : string.Empty
}).ToList<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to store attribute in additional variable. If attribute is not there, then [casting attribute to string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339184.aspx) will return `null`. With power of [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) you can provide default value - empty string:

```
from item in _documentRoot.Descendants("MyItems")
select new MyClass {
        XMLID = (string)item.Attribute("id") ?? ""
    }
```